# time.strptime got TypeError: function takes at most 8 arguments (9 given)

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I tested `time.strptime()`; it works:

```
In [2]: time.strptime(u'1994-03-30T00:00:00.000Z','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
Out[2]: time.struct_time(tm_year=1994, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=89, tm_isdst=-1)
```

but got:

```
TypeError: function takes at most 8 arguments (9 given)
```

for the following code:

```
import datetime
import time

data = [{u'volume': 249675300.0, u'date': u'1994-03-31T00:00:00.000Z'}, \
        {u'volume': 202356800.0, u'date': u'1994-03-30T00:00:00.000Z'}]   

map(lambda x:datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(x['date'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')), data )
print data
```

I'm hoping to replace all the date strings with `datetime` objects, preserving the rest:

```
[{u'volume': 249675300.0, u'date': datetime.datetime(1994, 3, 31, 0, 0)}, 
 {u'volume': 202356800.0, u'date': datetime.datetime(1994, 3, 30, 0, 0)}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.datetime()` doesn't accept the `wday`, `yday` and `is_dst` arguments; you'd have to slice the time tuple to the first 6 elements.

You don't need to use `time.strptime()` here, just use `datetime.datetime.strptime()`:

```
map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'), data)
```

Also see the [`datetime` documentation on using `strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> `datetime.strptime(date_string, format)` is equivalent to `datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string, format)[0:6]))`.

Demo:

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> time.strptime(u'1994-03-30T00:00:00.000Z','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
time.struct_time(tm_year=1994, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=89, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(u'1994-03-30T00:00:00.000Z','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')[:6])
datetime.datetime(1994, 3, 30, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(u'1994-03-30T00:00:00.000Z','%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
datetime.datetime(1994, 3, 30, 0, 0)
```

and using your sample input:

```
>>> data = [{u'volume': 249675300.0, u'date': u'1994-03-31T00:00:00.000Z'},
...         {u'volume': 202356800.0, u'date': u'1994-03-30T00:00:00.000Z'}]
>>> map(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'), data)
[datetime.datetime(1994, 3, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1994, 3, 30, 0, 0)]
```

If you wanted to preserve the rest of the dictionary, return a new dictionary from the `map()` function with the `'date'` key replaced:

```
map(lambda x: dict(x, date=datetime.datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')), data)
```

This produces:

```
[{u'volume': 249675300.0, u'date': datetime.datetime(1994, 3, 31, 0, 0)}, {u'volume': 202356800.0, u'date': datetime.datetime(1994, 3, 30, 0, 0)}]
```

Comment: Well,  that is not exactly what I want, in fact I want to convert the  [{ ... u'date': u'1994-03-31T00:00:00.000Z'...}]  to [{ ... u'date': datetime.datetime(1994, 3, 21, 0, 0) ...}] , Coz, I can insert it into mongodb by date type field.

Comment: @G.W.: sorry, *what*? I am doing exactly that. What do you want to convert *to* then? You didn't state any expected output. Your question was why you got an error, I explained that and showed a better way to parse time strings to `datetime` objects.

Comment: in fact I want to convert the [{ ... u'date': u'1994-03-31T00:00:00.000Z'...}] to [{ ... u'date': datetime.datetime(1994, 3, 21, 0, 0) ...}] , Coz, I can insert it into mongodb by date type field.

Comment: @G.W.: right, so you wanted to preserve the rest of the dictionary.

Comment: Exactly! I wanted to preserve the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Martijn Pieters answer,

```
import datetime

data = [{u'volume': 249675300.0, u'date': u'1994-03-31T00:00:00.000Z'},\
    {u'volume': 202356800.0, u'date': u'1994-03-30T00:00:00.000Z'}]

def transdate(dict_):
    dict_['date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(dict_['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    return dict_

data = map(trans, data)
print data
```